# PuTTY telnet option 63 (0x32), what should it be?

Tags: telnet, putty

For an application I had to develop a simple telnet module. (Which I could do quickly with the help of [minimalistic telnet](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/285035/minimalistic-telnet-interface))
I did create a telnet server and a client and I used PuTTY to test the behavior of the server.
PuTYY was configured for 'Telnet negotiation mode: active'.

In the server I did see the expected telnet negotiation sequence (and it was giving correct replies).
The last action in the PuTTY negotiation was a strange one.

`0xff 0xfe 0x32` or `IAC DONT 0x32`

The third byte, `0x32`, is the option and that is where the problem is (for me).
I did look up all Telnet options at [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/telnet-options/telnet-options.xhtml) and according to them the options range 50-137 is unassigned (`0x32` is 62).

What is behind PuTTY option `0x32`?
I have looked on the internet but can't find anything.
I have looked up the PuTTY documentation, same thing.
Putting up a request to the PuTTY development is severely discouraged due to capacity problems (not enough hands to type a sensible reply).

It is perfectly sensible not to use this unknown option but it still is nagging me.
What is option `0x3e` supposed to do?

Comment: Up to now no replies. I did put up this question to the PuTTY development team.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved.
There was an error in my server code causing PuTTY to generate a reply for a non existing option.

I hereby thank Simon Tatham for the suggestion he gave leading me to find the real problem.